# C# or WinJS : GridView scrollable with mouse?

Tags: c#, html, xaml, windows-8, winjs

I'm starting a Windows 8 application, and I've been trying to create a GridView that would behave like a Carousel/Coverflow, which means it would be scrollable with :

- finger touch (it works fine)
- mouse wheel (it works fine)
- mouse click&drag (it doesn't work on the GridView itself, only on the scrollbar)

My attempt in C#/XAML:

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="GoToItemDetails"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        />
```

My attempt in WinJS/HTML:

```
    <div
        data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
        data-win-options="{layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout},
                           itemDataSource: items.dataSource,
                           itemTemplate: select('.itemTemplate'),
                           selectionMode: 'none',
                           swipeBehavior: 'none'}"
        class="itemGridView win-selectionstylefilled"
        ></div>
```

For both, I couldn't find a way to allow mouse to click&scroll like it would be a finger touch. I don't want to use the tiny scrollbar, I want the whole GridView scrollable with mouse. Is that possible?

Comment: When you use a mouse with the GridView in either, can't you still scroll with the mouse wheel?

Comment: @GotDibbs, that's what I wrote in the question: "mouse wheel (it works fine)". But what I want is to do it with mouse click and drag, like a Carousel or Coverflow.

Comment: Ah missed that when I glanced last night. My guess is this isn't going to be easy in that case. People with a mouse are going to expect to scroll it with their mouse wheel anyways though since that would be more efficient, so is there a big reason to support click & drag? In JavaScript you'd probably need some fairly tricky logic to wait for clicks inside your grid div and then start tracking the mouse position. Long story short I'm pretty sure this isn't supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. The interaction patterns that you describe are what is expected for the ListView/GridView controls, namely:

- Touch - tap and drag to scroll
- Mouse - scroll with scroll wheel, or by clicking and dragging in the scroll bar
- Keyboard - scroll with L/R arrow keys or PgUp/PgDn/Home/End

The problem with the interaction pattern you're looking to add is that it fails in scenarios where the user might want to drag to rearrange the order of the items in the ListView/GridView (think about how the Start screen works). The controls must be able to support these scenarios, so they do not support the notion of scrolling via click and drag.

Hope that helps.

For more information on building Windows Store apps, register for [App Builder](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: In my case, items rearrangement is disabled: I'm providing a sorted list of results (by alphabetic order, price order, date order) and it would be more profitable to be able to scroll the list with mouse than to rearrange items with no effect. And think about it: Touch can both tap+drag and tap+rearrange. Why not mouse click?

Comment: Understood. But consistency of UX behavior is what's at issue here. If users of your app were able to click and drag to scroll, but other apps had different behavior, that leads to confusion and more difficulty for everyone. Following the guidance for touch and mouse interaction leads to apps that are easier to use for all.

Comment: For more information on the guidelines for these types of interactions, this link is really handy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465370.aspx